# how can I send a string with the following data to the next Slack Incoming Webhook

Tags: webhooks, slack, slack-api

how can I send a string with the following data to the next Slack Incoming Webhook https://hooks.slack.com/services/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

Answer (score 0):

Just post a request to the URL in JSON. e.g.:

```
{
   "text": "I would advise not to publish your real Slack webhooks on Stackoverflow. People might abuse it. :-D"
}
```

Other formats will work too.

You can use a website like https://www.hurl.it/ to test it.

There are more option you can use, e.g. channel. Check the official documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) for details.